# Gigya openid provider "Failed connecting. Please try again later" error

Tags: openid, gigya

I am implementing an openid provider server and I'm using the default Gigya widget for a custom provider (with the default API keys).

Everything works smoothly (discovery, association etc) up until the authentification response is sent to gigya, where it displays the following error message:

> Failed connecting. Please try again later.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: i have the same issue... but no clue how to fix